# How to change permission dialog language in the react-native android project?

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, localization, chinese-locale

I want to change the language of the permission allow string in the react-native android project.
I tried with the following code, but it opens the permission dialog twice.
The first dialog is with Chinese text, and the second dialog is with the English text. I want to open only the first one.
This is the [official guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid#request).

```
async function requestLocationPermission() {
 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
   const permissions = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
     PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
     {
       title: '申请权限',
       message: '在设置中请开启位置权限,以正常使用',
       buttonNeutral: '等再问我',
       buttonNegative: '拒绝',
       buttonPositive: '允许',
     },
   );
   if (permissions === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) resolve(true);
   else reject(false);
 });
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? @Yuji

Answer (score 0):

As I know, permission dialog language displays follow system language, so you cannot change it

Comment: What do you think about the example code in [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid#request)?